# How to change CSS for blockquotes in tutorial with learnr package

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, r-markdown

I am writing a tutorial with the `learnr` package and want to change the font size of the blockquote style. I am using the `cerulean` theme. My yaml header is:

```
output: 
    learnr::tutorial:
        progressive: true
        allow_skip: true
        theme: cerulean
        css: my-css.css
runtime: shiny_prerendered
```

In the same directory as my tutorial file "01-Chapter.Rmd" I have added a file "css/my-css.css" with the following content:

```
blockquote {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 5px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

I took these lines from inspecting the page in the browser and just changed font-size: 17.5px to font-size: 14px. But I cannot see any difference.

Inspecting the browser it tells me that I am using the css file "cerulean.min.css" in "bootstrap-3.3.5/css/cerulean.min.css" but the header of this file is from "bootswatch v3.3.6" and uses "Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)" I could not find this file on my hard disk.

I am using R version 3.5.0 with RStudio Version 1.1.453 on a Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5, rmarkdwon 1.10, shiny 1.1.0 and learnr 0.9.2.

Comment: Using `css: css/mystyle.css` works for me.

Comment: Yes! I didn't know that I had to write the relative path. I thought that every CSS has to be in a folder called `css` and so the program knows where to look. -- Would you mind to repeat your solution as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the relative path to your CSS:

```
css: css/mystyle.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding that custom paths are not allowed due to Shiny restrictions. You MUST use css/filename.css. (I'm not allowed to add comment to correct accepted answer.)

Comment: learnr doesn't appear to like using non css in different folders, it must be in the css/ folder